# stop php displaying to screen - run silent

Tags: php, linux, stdout

I have a php page that when called from a browser displays a page, it also generates a static html page so - http://somewebsite/create.php when run from a browser creates newpage.html.

I also run this page from the CLI #php create.php it creates newpage.html but I get all the output on the screen, this slows down execution and if I have to run it many times can take hours.

Is there a way to run #php create.php and to supress all output to the screen

MArtyn

Comment: Use your bash-syntax: append "&" at the end of the command. Or pipe it to /dev/null with |

Comment: Could you choose a correct answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pipe the output on the command-line to /dev/null such as:
`php http://somewebsite/create.php > /dev/null`

This doesn't actually stop output from being produced by php, only from being displayed.

If you actually want to stop the output from being produced, you could use php's output buffering with ob_start() and put the output into a variable with ob_get_flush() at the end of the code and only echo the output if a certain param is/is not passed to the script.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Output Buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php)

You begin with `ob_start()` to start buffering output, then you can use `$output = ob_get_clean()` to get everything that would have been displayed and store it in `$output`, so you can do whatever you want with it.

I believe there are `$_SERVER` variables you can use to check if you're running from the command line or not. (Obviously you can check for the HTTP headers that are normally there, they will not be set from the CLI)

`var_dump($_SERVER)` and see if there's anything intuitive looking :)